# React Native Maps Accessibility label error, Can't render map markers

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCaDr.png)

I am getting this error when trying to render a marker on the [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) packages MapView.  I have tried to update my version of react native but have encountered many other errors, so I am sticking with 0.38.1.  I have tried explicitly setting a prop called 'accessibilityLabel' with a string value but that doesn't work.

```
<MapView
  region={{
    latitude: this.state.lat,
    longitude: this.state.lng,
    latitudeDelta: this.state.latDelta,
    longitudeDelta: this.state.lngDelta,
  }}
  onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
>
  <MapView.Marker
    coordinate={this.state.marker.latlng}
    title={this.state.marker.title}
  />
</MapView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of react-native-maps are you using? did you tried to downgrade or upgrade the library to another version?

Comment: Im using 0.16.4 but Im not sure what other version I would use, how would I find out what versions to try?

Comment: You can find all the releases and information about releases [here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/releases)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this
[how to add contentDesctiption to InfoWindow or marker in Android GoogleMaps V2 for TalkBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990030/how-to-add-contentdesctiption-to-infowindow-or-marker-in-android-googlemaps-v2-f)

Android, at least, works when setting the marker's title or description prop to whatever you want the screen reader to say.